# html5 bug? details > summary > I tag with font awesome link, not clickable

Tags: html

Clicking a font awesome item inside a tag embedded inside of a details summary tag should result in visiting the link, instead details tag captures click event. Is this the expected behavior(I would not think so) or a bug in HTML5?

```
<details>
 <summary>
  Details
  <a href="http://google.com">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    Visit Google
  </a>
 </summary>
 <p> The Searching Site</p>
</details>
```

example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GGgyNz
*Note I think codepen overrides external links but the details tab should not be triggered when the Font Awesome tag is clicked*

**Incase pen is not working, Full HTML:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Details Tag and Font Awesome Link Issue</h2>
  <details>
    <summary>
      Details
      <a href="http://google.com">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Visit Google
      </a>
    </summary>
    <p> The Searching Site</p>
  </details>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function changeLocation() {
  window.location = "www.google.com";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Details Tag and Font Awesome Link Issue</h2>
  <details>
    <summary>
        Details
        <span onclick="changeLocation()">
          <a>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
            Visit Google
          </a>
        </span>
    </summary>
    <p> The Searching Site</p>
  </details>
</div>
```

I tag will not be directly clickable if you include in an anchor tag. 'onclick' event will do the work for you.